# iBatis : Insert into two different tables

Tags: spring, ibatis

Let's take examples: I have a registration form for a student which has following fields:

```
Name
Address
Email
Password
```

I want to insert some student details `(name, add, email)` in `student` table, and `email, password` in `login` table.

I am using iBatis.

How to achive this....?

Comment: iBatis isn't an ORM tool, it'a just a thin layer over JDBC. If you have 2 tables, you need two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a user class like follow

```
class User{

    private String name;
    private String add;
    private String email;
    private String password; 
    //getter setter
}
```

your mybatis mapper file should have something like this

```
    <insert id="insertInUser" parameterType="User">
        insert into user(name,add,email) values(#{name},#{add},#{email})
    </insert>

    <insert id="insertInLogin" parameterType="User">
        insert into login(email,password) values(#{email},#{password})
    </insert>
```